# Proof that $|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{U})| = |\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{U}) - \{\mathbb{U}\}|$, where $\mathbb{U}$ is infinity countable set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am asked to proof that the set of **all characteristic functions** of the sets $\mathbb{X} \subset \mathbb{U}$, where $\mathbb{U}$ is an infinite countable universe set, is uncountable. Let's call this set of all characteristic functions as
$$\mathbb{F} = \{f: \mathbb{U} \rightarrow \{0,1\} | (f^{-1}(1)=\mathbb{X}\subset\mathbb{U}) \wedge\ (f^{-1}(0)\cap\mathbb{X}=\emptyset\}).$$

My idea is to show that the cardinality of this set $\mathbb{F}$ is equal do the cardinality of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{U})$ which is greater than the cardinality of $\mathbb{U}$, $|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{U})| > |\mathbb{U}|$, and, therefore, it is not countable.

Well, each set $\mathbb{X}\subset\mathbb{U}$ has an unique characteristic function $f$ and each characteristic function $f$ is associated with an unique set $\mathbb{X}\subset\mathbb{U}$, therefore exists at least one bijection $g: \mathbb{F} \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{U})  - \{\mathbb{U}\}$.

And here I am stuck. Because, to proceed, I would like to prove that $|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{U})  - \{\mathbb{U}\}| = |\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{U})|$ to, hence, conclude that because $|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{U})| > |\mathbb{U}|$, $\mathbb{F}$ is not countable.

Comment: There is something weird going on. The notation $-$ in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{U}) - \mathbb{U}$ means that you start with $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{U})$ and then remove all elements from it that are also elements of $\mathbb{U}$, right?. But I don't see any elements of $\mathbb{U}$ sitting in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{U})$ in the first place. To stick with the case $\mathbb{U} = \mathbb{N}$ from the title: elements of $\mathbb{U}$ are *numbers* while elements of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{U})$ are *sets*. No overlap there I'd say,  so the action of 'removing all the numbers from a set of sets' doesn't do much.

Comment: What I meant with this notation is that the set $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{U})-\mathbb{U}$ is the set of all subsets of $\mathbb{U}$ minus the set $\mathbb{U}$ itself. For a finite set $\{a,b\}$ it would be $\{\emptyset , \{a\}, \{b\}\}$

Comment: If $\mathbb{U} = \{a,b\}$ then $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{U}) \setminus \mathbb{U} = \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{U})$, since $a, b \not\subseteq \mathbb{U}$. But  $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{U}) \setminus \{\mathbb{U}\} = \{\emptyset, \{a\}, \{b\}\}$.

Comment: I fixed my question. Thanks. 
I am doing all of this because I am working with the characteristic functions of $\mathbb{X} \subset \mathbb{U}$ and not with $\mathbb{X} \subseteq \mathbb{U}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you delete one item from any infinite set, the remaining set is the same size.  It doesn't matter whether the set is countable or not.  Proving $|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{U})  - \{\mathbb{U}\}| = |\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{U})|$ will not help you prove that $\Bbb F$ is uncountable.  The claim that $\Bbb |F|=|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{U})| > |\mathbb{U}|$ is correct and shows that $\Bbb F$ is uncountable, where the greater than comes from Cantor's theorem.

Comment: Proving $|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{U}) - \{\mathbb{U}\}| = |\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{U})|$ will not help you prove that  is uncountable. Why not? If I do this, I could state that $|\mathbb{F}|=|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{U}) - \{\mathbb{U}\}| = |\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{U})| > |\mathbb{U}|$.

But, it is ok. I will just affirm that when an item is removed from an infinite set that cardinality of set remains the same.